# What is an integer(255) field in SQLite 3.0 and do I need to change it?

Tags: sqlite, integer

I have a DB in a Rails app I'm developing that had a `product_type` field defined as varchar(255) (in SQLite Manager) that ended up being a foreign key. I changed the name to `product_type_id` and the type to `integer` using a migration in Rails to use the existing id field in the other `product_type` file. When it was complete, SQLite Manager in Firefox shows the type as `integer(255)` rather than just `integer`.

What is an `integer(255)`? An answer to another question here said the (255) was a display width. Is that correct? There is no data in the database at present. Should I delete and recreate the field to get an `integer`, otherwise the data types on the two fields won't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `integer(255)` came about because a string field [ `varchar(255)` ] was converted to an integer and the DB maintained the field size so it might possibly hold the old data when converted during the change. Apparently, most DBs don't support integers that large. Some will ignore the size specification but others will error. Regardless, the result was not what I'd intended.

I found that the way to remove the limit was to perform a migration in Rails and set the limit to nil.

```
class RemoveIntegerLimits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_column :inv_x_refs, :company_id, :integer, limit: nil
  end
end
```